# Como descobrir se um ImageView possui uma foto informada

Tags: java, android, imageview

Olá, quero criar um condicional que verifica se todos os campos da tela foram informados pelo usuário ou não. Caso algum não tenha sido informado, gostaria de apresentar um toast mostrando o erro. O problema é que nesta tela eu possuo um ImageView e não consigo descobrir quando ele foi informado ou não.

Código desta função:

```
if ((edtTitulo.getText().toString().isEmpty()) ||   (edtPreparo.getText().toString().isEmpty()) || (edtIngredientes.getText().toString().isEmpty())){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Todos os campos são obrigatórios", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

Como acrescentar o ImageView vazio nesta condição?

Comment: É isso mesmo @AndersonSantos eu implementei um método que permite o usuário selecionar uma imagem da galeria e queria saber se ele preencheu este campo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependendo do método que usou para atribuir a foto à ImageView use

```
if(imageView.getDrawable() != null)
```

ou

```
if(imageView.getBackground() != null)
```

Comment: A primeira opção funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado